# enum to dropdownlist MVC3 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently using this for turning an enum into a radio control,

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForEnum<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var enumType = metaData.ModelType;
    foreach (var field in enumType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        var value = (int)field.GetValue(null);
        var name = Enum.GetName(enumType, value);
        var label = name;
        foreach (DisplayAttribute currAttr in field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true))
        {
            label = currAttr.Name;
            break;
        }

        var id = string.Format(
            "{0}_{1}_{2}",
            htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix,
            metaData.PropertyName,
            name
        );
        var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, name, new { id = id }).ToHtmlString();
        sb.AppendFormat(
            "<label for=\"{0}\">{1}</label> {2}",
            id,
            HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(label),
            radio
        );
    }
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
}
```

but when trying to adapt it to enum to dropdown:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListForEnum<TModel, TProperty>(
   this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
   Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
     var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

     var sb = new StringBuilder();
     var enumType = metaData.ModelType;
     sb.Append("<select name=\"" + metaData.PropertyName + "\" id=\"" + metaData.PropertyName + "\" > ");
     foreach (var field in enumType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Public))
     {
          var value = (int)field.GetValue(null);
          var name = Enum.GetName(enumType, value);
          var label = name;

          foreach (DisplayAttribute currAttr in field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true))
          {
                label = currAttr.Name;
                break;
          }

          var id = string.Format(
                    "{0}_{1}_{2}",
                    htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix,
                    metaData.PropertyName,
                    name
                );
          var listitem = htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, name, new { id = id }).ToHtmlString();
          sb.AppendFormat(
                    "<option value=\"{0}_{1}\">{2}</option> ",
                    id,
                    listitem,
                    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(label)
                );
     }
     sb.Append("</select>");
     return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
}
```

I get an error in the `var listitem = htmlHelper.DropDownListFor` line. Basically I'm not providing the correct information in the method. Could anyone shed any light on this issue?

Comment: The `DropDownListFor()` method renders the entire drop-down list, complete with all the `<select>` tags. So you only need to call it once, not inside `foreach`.

Comment: Why don't you just follow ASP.NET MVC - Creating a DropDownList helper for enums (Stuart Leeks) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/05/21/asp-net-mvc-creating-a-dropdownlist-helper-for-enums.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a static helper that turns enums into select lists.

I've blogged about it here:

http://jnye.co/Posts/4/creating-a-dropdown-list-from-an-enum-in-mvc-and-c%23

The helper (this will get the value of the description attribute if present):

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    public static SelectList SelectListFor<T>(T? selected)
        where T : struct
    {
        return selected == null ? SelectListFor<T>()
                                : SelectListFor(selected.Value);
    }

    public static SelectList SelectListFor<T>() where T : struct
    {
        Type t = typeof (T);
        if (t.IsEnum)
        {
            var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<Enum>()
                             .Select(e => new { Id = Convert.ToInt32(e), Name = e.GetDescription() });

            return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static SelectList SelectListFor<T>(T selected) where T : struct 
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        if (t.IsEnum)
        {
            var values = Enum.GetValues(t).Cast<Enum>()
                             .Select(e => new { Id = Convert.ToInt32(e), Name = e.GetDescription() });

            return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name", Convert.ToInt32(selected));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static string GetDescription<TEnum>(this TEnum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        if (fi != null)
        {
            DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
                (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
                    typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
                    false);

            if (attributes.Length > 0)
                return attributes[0].Description;
        }

        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

This helper will enable you to convert an enum to a select list in just two lines.

In your controller:

```
ViewBag.TypeDropDown = EnumHelper.SelectListFor(field);
```

In your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("TypeDropDown")
```

Comment: But there isn't a method declared for `DropDownFor`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it should be @Html.DropDownList("TypeDropDown").

I have updated my answer, thanks

Comment: Cheers, I changed the code a little to match into my class but it seems to work. I take it that this code won't automatically persist into my model (Like when using TextboxFor etc)

Comment: If you mean when posting a form, then yes, the selected value will be posted up to your action method as part of the viewmodel

Comment: Cool, I decided to grab the information with `FormCollection` in the end instead of grabbing the viewmodel. But that's due to the nature of my project. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum test
    {
        a = 0,
        b = 1
    }
```

then, put below in Html Extension

```
var options = Enum.GetValues(typeof(test))// u can pass type as parameter
.OfType<object>()
.Select(each => new {key = Enum.GetName(typeof(test), each), value = each})
.Select(each => string.Format("<option value=\"{1}\">{0}</option>", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(each.key), each.value))
.Aggregate((cur, nex) => cur + nex);

return "<select name=...>"+options+"</select>";
```

Comment: this would be ok, except I need it to hook in with the display attribute in my MVC model like my code for RadioButtonFor

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EnumExtensions
  {
    public static IEnumerable GetEnumSelectList()
    {
      return
        new SelectList(
          Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast().Select(
            x =>
            new
            {
              Value = x.ToString(),
              Text = x.ToString()
            }).ToList(),
        "Value",
        "Text");
    }
  }
```